# pandas json_normalize nested json where dictionary only exists on some records

Tags: json, pandas, nested, normalize

I am trying to run pandas.json_normalize on a data file that has highly varied, nested json, where the content of the records can vary considerably.

I am processing a house listing file and trying to pull out prices. The prices data is stored as follows, and 'prices' is at the first nesting level within the json file:

```
       "prices": [
            {
                "amountMax": 420000,
                "amountMin": 420000,
                "availability": "false",
                "currency": "USD",
                "dateSeen": [
                    "2020-12-21T11:57:17.190Z",
                    "2020-12-25T02:35:41.009Z"
                ],
                "isSale": "false",
                "isSold": "true",
                "pricePerSquareFoot": 235,
                "sourceURLs": [
                    "https://www.redfin.com/FL/Coconut-Creek/.../home/4146834"
                ]
            }, # followed by additional entries
```

I am using the following line of code, which works if I edit the input file down to a single record that includes a 'prices' section:

```
df3 = pd.json_normalize(df['records'], record_path='prices',
                meta=['id'],
                errors='ignore'                        
                )
```

However, the full file includes many records that do not include a prices section.  If I run the code against a file with 2 records (one with, one without), it fails with KeyError: 'prices'

Clearly the 'errors='ignore'' in the json_normalize is not enough to handle the error.

What can I do?  I would just like to skip the records without prices entirely.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension on your JSON will do it.  I've synthesized some JSON to match your description of input data.

```
js = {
  "records": [
    {
      "prices": [
        {
          "amountMax": 420000,
          "amountMin": 420000,
          "availability": "false",
          "currency": "USD",
          "dateSeen": [
            "2020-12-21T11:57:17.190Z",
            "2020-12-25T02:35:41.009Z"
          ],
          "isSale": "false",
          "isSold": "true",
          "pricePerSquareFoot": 235,
          "sourceURLs": [
            "https://www.redfin.com/FL/Coconut-Creek/.../home/4146834"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": 1
    },{"id":2}
  ]
}
pd.json_normalize({"records":[r for r in js["records"] if "prices" in r.keys()]}["records"],record_path="prices",meta="id")
```